# Magento 2 - Product filters using Observer Event

Tags: magento, magento2

I am trying to create one observer for apply additional filters to product collection.

So I use magento 2 event :catalog_product_collection_load_after

Observer code is :

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('size',10);
        return $this;
    }
```

But above code working fine with product collection, but showing wrong pagination and product count

Same happen for layer navigation.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: did you find any solution to your problem ?

Comment: Hi, did u find any solution

Comment: did you find any solution to your problem ?

Comment: No solution found yet? having the same problem during multiple events.
the product collection gets filtered just fine, but the count and pagination is all wrong

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver as LayerResolver;

class CatalogProductCollectionLoadAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category
     */
    protected $catalogLayer;

    /**
     * @param LayerResolver $layerResolver,
     */
    public function __construct(
        LayerResolver $layerResolver
    ) {
        $this->catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // Get selected filters
        $layer         = $this->catalogLayer;
        $activeFilters = $layer->getState()->getFilters();
    }
}
```